# Tracking Unsubs and New Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics

So, I have two brands within the same BU and want to report on the total unsubs and total new subscribers on a monthly cadence. Normally this would be easily done with a List Growth Over Time Standard Report / Unengaged Subscribers for a List Standard Report / Tracking Extract / Data View or Discover Report. The issue is in breaking down that information and splitting it between brands when new subscriptions are tracked in the AllSubscribers list. Short of creating a Discover report for unsubs for all DEs used for sends within a month, (and I don't think there's an option for tracking new subscribers with Discover other than through customisation), is there any other way of getting this information short of paid-for services? I'm not sure whether it could be achieved with a query activity or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go for any paid service. But you might have to some customization for this logic. Am assuming that you will use to different emails for different products for sending.

**For Un-subscription:**

You have many reports, You can go to `Catalogue > Discovery reports > Recent email send summary` You can find the emails associated with un-subscription.

You can export the report and segment un-subscription based upon your product emails

**For New subscribers:**

Get all the new subscribers with the query below:

You can change the data as per your requirement (within 6 months of data)
This query is merging Job, Send and All subscriber list and will return Email name and subscriber key and created date. Post that based upon email name you can segment with products.

```
Select
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
j.DeliveredTime as SendTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey,
s.CreatedDate 
from [_Job] j
join [_Sent] o
on j.JobID = o.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
where
s.ListID = <ListID> and
s.CreatedDate between '2020-04-01' and '2020-05-01'
```

**For Future:**

You can add a section in profile management or if you have any master data extension you can add a section called 'Brand'.

Add a snippet of ampscript to add the 'brand' either in all subscriber list or master data extension. So that it will be easy for you to segment.

Let me know if this helps.